# Joining on deletion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm working with mysql:

- btableA has tableB_id column
- tableB has some_interestring_column_on_TableB

I want (pseudo sql below):

```
delete from tableA 
 where the associated row in tableB (via tableB_id) has  
     some_interestring_column_on_TableB = 'interestingValue'
```

Please help me to translate the pseudo sql into real sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL supports JOINs in the DELETE statement, as well as deleting from multiple tables in a single statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).  The following will only delete from TABLEA:

```
DELETE ta
  FROM TABLEA ta
  JOIN TABLEB tb ON b.id = a.tableb_id
                AND b.col = 'some value'
```

If you wanted to delete from both tables, use:

```
DELETE ta, tb
  FROM TABLEA ta
  JOIN TABLEB tb ON b.id = a.tableb_id
                AND b.col = 'some value'
```

That said, this support is very uncommon in other databases -- you'd have to use `IN` or `EXISTS` in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 DELETE TableA
 WHERE tableB_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM TableB 
    WHERE  interestring_column='pizza');
```

Comment: good but will be inefficient if tableB is much larger than tableA or if interesting_column doesn't have an index

Comment: @gid: no matter what you come to, if you don't have an index, your performance will be poor. `IN` is quite fast. Debatable whether a `LEFT JOIN` would be faster. You're stating that it's inefficient. Have you benchmarked it? Why *isn't* there an index if you *know* that it'll increase performance? *Anything* will be inefficient without proper indexing, tuning, and DB statistics.

Comment: maybe. Generally joins considered usually better practice than nested queries. Sure, this is not 100% rule. I showed one case when it will be better for sure, if tableB is much larger. Anyway, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mysql syntax but I'm thinking something like (from mssql):

```
delete from tableA 
where tableA.tableB_id in 
   (select tableB.id from tableB 
   where tableB.some_interesting_column_on_TableB = 'interestingValue')
```